# Firefox not giving the complete path

Tags: html, file, asp-classic

I am creating a file copy program in ASP classic for our subject. It works fine in IE but not in firefox. I need to let the user browse for a file using input type file but whenever i get the value, it only returns the filename not the complete path(In firefox). I search the internet but no luck. Is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks in advance

```
<%

    if (Request.Form("btnSave")<>"" )then

         dim fis
         Set fis = Server.createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
         Response.write(Request.Form("txtPath"))
         dim path
         path= Server.Mappath("\sample\images") & "\"
         Response.write(path)
         dim source
         source =Request.Form("txtPath")
         response.write(source)
         fis.CopyFile source, path
         set fso = nothing
   End If
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a file upload input control and post it to the page using

```
<input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
```

Checkout this link for a tutorial: [ASP File Upload Example](http://www.chestysoft.com/upload/filedemo.asp)

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. Scripting.FileSystemObject can be used just fine with server side code and it does not matter what browser is used. However you are right about the need to upload the file, as server side code can't copy files from the client machine just like that.

Comment: Oops, you're right Shadow Wizard. I removed the incorrect comment to avoid confusion for future visitors. Thanks for the correction.